# Redirecting depends of Variables in Header

Tags: redirect, 301-redirect, ibm-domino

**Issue**

I've difficulties to understand if it is possible to do redirects depends of variable in Header using Domino server (R9).

**AIM**

Redirect all requests (for 1 particular website) to: `https://www.domain`

**EXAMPLE**
incoming requests:

- `http://example.com`
- `http://www.example.com`
- `https://example.com`

All 3 examples should be redirected to

- `https://www.example.com`

**Here is my setup**

1. All requests come to "Load Balancer" and then it redirect requests to Domino Server.
2. Load Balancer always (!) convert requests from HTTPS to HTTP, so Domino always receives HTTP requests.
3. Load Balancer adds flag/variable to requests which have been converted from HTTPS to HTTP.
4. Domino must redirect HTTP to HTTPS. My issue - I need to figure out how to verify variable in request and depends of it - do redirect to HTTPS or NOT.
5. So far if I set redirect for all request - I receive a loop and I understand why.

Does anybody have an idea how to solve that only with Domino Server?

**Possible solutions I know about**

1. Setup one more server between Load Balancer and Domino, so it does redirect instead of Domino.
2. Go with DSAPI. I really would like to avoid it, it requires development + maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

We've not found a way to do that with native IBM Domino capabilities, so we setup an additional server (nginx) between LoadBalancer and Domino and configured everything on nginx instead.